# Are hosting requests banned?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope, faq-update-request

So I ask [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295854/cheap-django-host-with-free-developer-mode/8297187#8297187), get some incredibly useful answers, then it gets closed. Judging from other closed questions with the hosting tag, such questions are banned? Maybe the FAQ needs to be updated, because as I read it, these questions are fine:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
> - practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face

Needing hosting for (non-professional) web app development is exactly these three things.

And it's not any of these:

> If your question would be of interest to …
>
> - System administrators and desktop support professionals, ask on Server Fault.
> - Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on Super User.
> - Pro webmasters, ask on Webmasters.
> - Professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development, ask on Programmers.

So if hosting request questions are out, the FAQ should be updated. (And personally, I think they should be allowed - the answer given by Lakshman Prasad was much better than the list given on the Django website).

Comment: Shopping questions are generally off-topic throughout the Stack Exchange network.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements

Comment: And see my request to get the "shopping list" ban actually mentioned in FAQs here: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/977/not-constructive-really

Is it really unreasonable to ask that this unstated rule actually get put in the FAQ?

Comment: -10 points for my question. WTF?

Answer (score 14):

Please use common sense.

Hosting questions are not directly programming related. They don't have a lasting value for the community. And they are subjective (my perfect host differs from your perfect host).

So please don't ask them on stackoverflow. Unless you like to get your question closed quickly.

Comment: Well, I disagree. "Where can I host my experimental django app" seems just as programming related as a question about Eclipse, Sax, books on programming, version control, etc. And it's not subjective: I asked for specific attributes, not "the perfect host".